# Matplotlib: Only show XY pane in Axes3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a 3D scatter plot I want to show only the XY pane and restrict XY grid lines only to that pane (i.e. I want to preserve gridlines in XY). Is that possible? I got as far as disabling the Z axis and grid lines:

```
 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 import numpy as np

 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
 ax.set_xlabel('x')
 ax.set_ylabel('y')
 ax.get_zaxis().set_ticks([])
 ax.get_zaxis().line.set_linewidth(0)

 data = np.random.randn(100,3)
 ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.get_zaxis().set_ticks([])
ax.get_zaxis().line.set_linewidth(0)
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)) # Hide YZ Plane
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)) # Hide XZ Plane
ax.grid(False) # HIde All Gridlines


data = np.random.randn(100,3)
ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's close. However, I would like to preserve the grid lines within the XY pane.